# How do I emit box drawing characters on the Linux console when the character set is ISO-8859-1?

Tags: c, linux

How do I output these characters? It sounds impossible, but it isn't. `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` can do this.

I wrote this looking for the characters and could not find them (a couple of the box drawing characters appear in the holes in ISO-8859-1 but that's not a usable set):

```c
#!/usr/bin/tcc -run

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0: case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 27:
            printf(". %3d ", i);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c %3d ", i, i);
            break;
        }
        if ((i % 16) == 15) printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I was expecting an answer would look like `printf("...");` but I don't actually know that.

Comment: Any reason you can't use UTF-8?  Seems like that would be more robust.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Because the console can't be set to UTF-8.

Comment: Which console is this?  I thought Linux was pretty universal in supporting UTF-8 across the board.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It is, as soon as you get X up, or most of the advanced video drivers. But the early boot VGA text console can't do it.

Comment: Seems like a pretty rare use case, needing to display fancy characters before boot.  Glad you found an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that works for North American PCs.

```c
printf("\033(U");
```

Switches to ROM character set, which is CP437 here, and graphics characters appear.

```c
printf("\033(B");
```

Switches to ISO-8859-1.

If these terminal sequences are used, they don't change characters already displayed, thus we can even mix the character sets on the output.